# Help me understand the expression including operator norm?

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, integral-inequality

If $\mathscr{L}$ is a normal operator, mathematically, we have the formula

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}=i \int_0^\infty \exp(-i t \mathscr{L})dt.\tag{1}$$

**My question:**

**1.** On the basis of the above equation, how can I see the following inequation?

$$\| \mathscr{L}^{-1} \| \le \int_0^\infty \| \exp (-i t \mathscr{L}) \| dt;$$

**2.** In practice, why this inequality is typically within a factor of 2 of equality?

I understand that the RHS of Eq.(1) is equivalent to rotate the complex number
$\int_0^\infty \exp(-i t \mathscr{L})dt$ by $90^\circ$ anticlockwise. And a key point of my question is related to the *the norm of an operator*? Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the triangle inequality. An integral is a limit of sums. And for a sum you have 
$$
\left\| \sum_{j=1}^n \exp(-it_j\mathscr L)\,\Delta_j\right\|\leq\sum_{j=1}^n\|\exp(-it_j\mathscr L)\|\,\Delta_j
$$

Comment: Thanks @Martin Argerami for your answer. A further question is: Why this inequality is typically within a factor of 2 of equality?

Comment: I don't know your basis to say this. If you take $\mathscr L$ to be a selfadjoint unitary, then $\|\mathscr L\|=\|\mathscr L^{-1}\|=1$, while the integral is infinite.

Comment: Hi @Martin Argerami, in the context of the paper to which I referred, $\mathscr{L}$ is the linearized Orr-Sommerfeld operator, which is in many cases non-selfadjoint.

Comment: I don't really know what that is, but my point is that this inequality is brutal; it would be an exception to have it close to equality.

Comment: @ Martin Argerami, thank you for the help anyway.